# How do I animate the text on Lable like slot machine?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, bitmap-fonts, cclabelttf

i would like to perform an animation on label text.i need to show 10 on label. the label should display first start with 0 then 1 ,2 ,3....end with 10.

example : showing display number animation is seems like in slot wheel.

how should i achieve that? is it any trick in cocos 2d?

Has anybody got a clue how to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First setup the label as an instance variable.

```
// In your .h
CCTabelTTF *_myLabeL;
```

Then (assuming you have already added it in your project) create an update method for it

```
- (void)updateLabel {
    int currentVal = [_myLabel intValue];
    NSString *newString;

    currentVal += 1;
    newString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", currentVal];

    [_myLabel setString:newString];
}
```

Now we can create a method to call your update:

```
- (void)startUpdatingLabel:(int)newValue {
    int curVal = [_myLabel intValue];
    int difference = newValue-curVal;
    for(int i=0; i > difference; i++) {
        [self performSelector:@select(updateLabel) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
    }
}
```

Then all you have to do whenever you want to update the label (say to 10) is to call

```
[self startUpdatingLabel:10];
```

and it will update your label by 1 every 1 second until it reaches the new value

Comment: hi Brandon Lassiter,

could you check your mail.